# JQuery Mobile <LI> Text length

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile and have an `<LI>` with some long text (A Description).

My problem is that it's only displaying a few words following by "..." (3 dots)

How can I make it show the whole string please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use formatting like JQMobile mentions in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/lists-inset.html)

[image]

and then overwrite/replace/add your own the `.ui-li-desc` for example with `white-space: normal;` instead the existing `white-space: nowrap;`

so you can have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set `white-space: normal;` on the CSS of whatever the LI element is.