# Want to wrap text into div in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have problem to display long text into div they have no space.I want to display this text into next line.

[image: Pleae check the below image, I want to display text of **object**]

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile <LI> Text length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064382/jquery-mobile-li-text-length)

Comment: please **search the forum** prior to create a question, you will be amazed how many answers there are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I have used css `word-wrap:break-word` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS in the right place and you'll have what you need...

white-space: normal;